# Share objects between people who are using the same app in real-time (push)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm pretty new to objective-c, so i came up with this..I've found other similar questions, like mine, but there were all different at some point..

So, i have a tableview which contains cells, and the cells are containing data (NSManagedObjectModels). I have this app on **1 device**, and I'd like to share these cells, i mean data, with other people, who are using the **exact same app** (**i'd  like to use only wifi or network connection**). 
Just like in Reminders (*in iOS pre-installed app*) when i create a new list, i have the option to share it with someone else(s), and the person who i've shared with, can see the list i created-immediately.

Is there a simple, or any way to accomplish that?

Comment: I guess simplicity is a subjective matter that has a lot to do with experience. You will have to have a backend that collects the changes and is in charge of synching. The app would probably send a "ping" to the server every short time interval and find out if theres new information. If there is it would download and display it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to send a push notification to all users with a URL linking to data you want to share.

But even that means that you'll have to have a server store away details of push tokens (so you can push to each device) and then provide some way for users to group different devices...

I would look the sessions on CloudKit and see if from that you can see a way to do what you want, otherwise look at libraries that provide easy server integration to make passing data up to the server easier.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to do realtime location sharing as well. Like "Find my friends" app where many users location are pinned in the same map. Can you give me any ideas, where to start, where to look?? Please answer. Thank you.

Comment: Try looking into using GameKit?

Comment: Can't really give you much advice beyond what I wrote - a server component that shares information with multiple separate groups adds a lot of complexity that you need to be able to deal with. There's no one thing I can really direct you at other than some technologies as mentioned that might make such a thing easier to build.  CloudKit is the most likely to help, though GameKit was a good suggestion too... but then people would have to share location through GameCenter.